# How do I read a csv file from inside a docker container postgres:12?

Tags: pandas, postgresql, docker, volumes

I want to import a csv file, into the postgreSQL table inside the docker-compose container from the image postgres:12. I can read the file from the application backend, for example:

```
pd.read_csv(pth.dirname(__file__) + '/file_name.csv')
```

Where file path is:

```
/opt/project/backend_api/directory_name
```

but when I try to access the same file from the container `\copy data_table(id, ...)  FROM '/opt/project/backend_api/directory_name/file_name.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;` 
No such file or directory error.
So how I can allow to the container to read this path, or how to add the file to location where I'll be able to reach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...how to add the file to location where I'll be able to reach it?`

Since your container already running, you can copy the file into the container: `docker cp file_name.csv <container id>:/opt/project/backend_api/directory_name/file_name.csv` and try your pg command.